# modify input content into a div

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <title>consultation</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/consultation.css">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var date_1;

            //setInterval( functionDate() , 999 );

            function functionDate()
            {
                //alert( form_1.length );
                date_1 = new Date();
                date_1 = date_1.getHours() + ":" + date_1.getMinutes() + ":" + date_1.getSeconds(); 
                form_1.date.value = ""; 
                form_1.date.value = "date_1";
            }

        </script>


    </head>

    <body>
        <form name="form_1" >
        <div id="container">

                <div id="header">
                    <img src="images/picture_1.png" id="image" width="60" height="60">
                    <p id="select_product_p">
                        Select product:
                    </p>

                    <input list="product" id="select_product">
                    <datalist id="product" >
                        <option>Tortilla</option>
                        <option>Masa</option>
                    </datalist>

                    <p id="product_amount_p">
                        Product amount:
                    </p>
                    <input type="number" id="product_amount" min="1">

                    <p id="unit_price_p">
                        Unit price:
                    </p>
                    <input type="number" id="unit_price" min="1" size="5">

                    <button type="button" id="add_product">Add Product</button>

                    <input type="text" name="hour" id="hour_id">

                <!--
                </div>
                <div id="medium">

                </div>
                <div id="final">

                </div>                  
        </div>
        -->
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

im trying to build a clock whit a setInterval and then put the our on input tag but i dont know why is wrong. i know that i can change the value on tag. thinking maybe i can use a .innerHTML. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I get what you want to achieve, but to set time to your input field, you can do this:

```
var nowDate = new Date();
var timeString = nowDate.getHours() + ":" + nowDate.getMinutes() + ":" + nowDate.getSeconds();

document.getElementById("hour_id").value = timeString;
```

Comment: i take your advice like this: var date_1;
   var date_2;
   setInterval( functionDate() , 999 );

   function functionDate()
   {
    //alert( form_1.length );
    date_1 = new Date();
    date_2 = date_1.getHours() + ":" + date_1.getMinutes() + ":" + date_1.getSeconds(); 
    document.getElementById( "hour_id" ).value = date_2; 
    form_1.date.value = "date_1";
   }

Comment: and get a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null" thank you very much.

Comment: Nothing wrong with my code. Check this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fx9gto2o/

This means that <input type="text" name="hour" id="hour_id">is not loaded in your doom when you try to document.getElementById("hour_id"), and therefor it's null